# looping in a node.js callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can I run a loop (while, for, dowhile etc) in a callback function. Here is a sample code :

```
var execute = function (data,callback) 
{
    //do something with data
    callback();
}

execute (data,function(error,returnDataArray)
{
    var boo = true;
    while(boo)
    {
        //do something with returnDataArray
        if (returnDataArray.length == 10) 
            boo=false;
    }
});
```

Now, my doubt is, does the main node.js thread wait until the above while loop is executed?

Comment: Why wouldn't node wait ? Is your loop so long it could trigger a timeout ?

Comment: yes it will wait, user a different process if it's gonna take forever...

Comment: Hmmm, did you even try?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yes, I tried. It seemed to me like the entire main thread is waiting

Answer (score 2):

Your main thread will be blocked by the looping occuring inside a callback function. That's because callback functions are just delayed until completion, and then, they're pushed into the JavaScript event loop and executed once the thread is free. In simpler word, everything in node (and JavaScript) happen in a single thread (normal execution, callback, timeouts, etc).

The only way to execute a function into another thread with JavaScript is manually pushing it into another thread. In browser that'll be a web worker, and on node a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this

```
var execute = function (data,function(error,returnDataArray)
{
  //do something with data
  var boo = true;
  while(boo)
  {
    //do something with returnDataArray
    if (returnDataArray.length == 10) 
        boo=false;
  }
});
```

or you can use the async module, using function async.parallel

Comment: +1 async module - don't loop, try map/reduce or recursion, but not looping.  Map lok like it would work for you

Comment: You can't say "don't loop" without knowing what's inside the loop. Loop aren't forbidden in node.

Comment: I agree with both @dystroy that it is not forbidden to use loops, however since node is asynchronous loops tend to get ugly while running and can give unexpected results if not used properly, hence the modules like async are very helpful

Comment: @dystroy, I was probably a bit quick on the "don't loop" trigger, but my assumption is that he needs to block in the loop, and then things go south from there.  I'm no master, been using node about 4 months.